# There is not any go to top link on any of the site of stack

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is not any go to top link on any of the site of stack, specially on the questions page, as when user scroll down to the end of the page there must be a link that bring user to the top,

Comment: This has featured on [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/what-reasons-are-there-for-go-to-bottom-top-links-no-longer-being-used-much).

Comment: But this is a feature that could be added in the site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does there need to be?

<kbd>Home</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>) will take you to the top of the page.

Comment: Not all keyboards have a HOME key... MacBook Air, yes, I'm looking at you! =)

Comment: @Rob well if you will use an inferior device, what do you expect :)

Comment: it gets better once you install Windows on it ;)

Comment: But this is a feature that could be added in the site, what is wrong with it

Comment: @Farid - yes it *could* be added, but it's not stopping you using the site (except for a smallish number of users)