# Request for scroll to Top feature

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back to Top Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134553/back-to-top-button)
>   [There is not any go to top link on any of the site of stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146225/there-is-not-any-go-to-top-link-on-any-of-the-site-of-stack)

In the forum we have some 15/30/50 questions per page. As we start scroll to bottom feature of scroll to top would be better.

Comment: There's a bunch of browser add-ons that will do this for you, without having to glom on dubious features to the site. I like the [Scroll To Top Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chiikmhgllekggjhdfjhajkfdkcngplp) extension for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll on the top is not more useful since you can sort the question on the basis of the tag.

Comment: Sorting doesn't help when there are hundreds of questions in the tag.